# How to search co-exist elements in multiple string vectors in R

Tags: r

Here is an example:

```
    elem<-c("A1", "B2")
    set.list<-list(
       set1=c("G1", "H2", "C3", "F6", "A1", "D4"),
       set2=c("F6", "C3", "E5", "D4", "B2", "H2"),
       set3=c("A1", "B2", "B2", "E5", "F6", "D4"),
       set4=c("A1", "D4", "H2", "F6", "E5", "C3","F6", "B2", "D4", "A1"))
```

What I wanted to return is the number of sets that the `elem` e.g. A1 and B2 coexist in a set that would be n=2 because set3 and set4 have both A1 and B2 rather set1 and set2 not.

Comment: Not sure about your desired result. Can you show your expected output to avoid confusion?

Comment: The output would be set3 and set4 becuase they have both A1 and B2.

Comment: Try `all(elem %in% set1)` or as function `f1 <- function(x, y) all(x %in% y);
 f1(elem, set1)`

Comment: Do you want to return the lists themselves, or a character vector `c("set3", "set4")`?

Comment: If it is for the `list` `sapply(set.list, f1, x = elem)`

Comment: Just the count would be great e.g. 2 (2 sets have the element)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
sum(sapply(set.list, function(set) ifelse(all(elem %in% set), 1, 0)))
```

---

Or `sum(sapply(set.list, function(x) all(elem %in% x)))`, ifelse is not needed (see comment by @markus)

Comment: `%in%` in another option: `sum(sapply(set.list, function(x) all(elem %in% x)))`, i.e. no need for `ifelse`

Answer (score 1):

An option would be `all` to check the whether all the elements in 'elem' is found in each of the `list` elements

```
f1 <- function(x, y) all(x %in% y)
i1 <- sapply(set.list, f1, x = elem)
```

If it is the total count

```
sum(i1)
#[1] 2
```

---

If it is the count per each element

```
sapply(set.list, function(x) sum(elem %in% x))
```